# Браузер не выводит http ответ

Tags: http, tcp, erlang

Что происходит...

Я принимаю tcp соединение, получаю пакет, отдаю ответ вот примерно так:

```
Header=list_to_binary("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n Content-Type: text/html, charset=utf-8\r\n Connection: Close \r\nContent-Length: "),
M=unicode:characters_to_binary(M1++M2),
R=io_lib:fwrite("~s~p~s", [Header, size(M), M]),
gen_tcp:send(S, R),
```

где M1 и M2 части тела `<html> и </html>`

Если всё это реализовать на прямом Erlang, всё нормально, данные есть, браузер доволен. Если упаковать в gen_server , то выглядит так, будто браузер ожидает окончания передачи данных, а потом сбрасывает коннект. Закрытие соединения не влияет никак, как будто gen_server продолжает удерживать коннект.
Куда копать?

Comment: Возможно надо дать команду `gen_tcp:close`?

Comment: Так я и даю сразу после ответа.

Comment: Я не знаком с Erlang и могу ошибаться, но этот код создаёт у меня ощущение, что после заголовков не добавлена пустая строка `\r\n\r\n`

Comment: Хедер завершается длиной полезной нагрузки, после чего две штатные пустые строки.

Comment: Я считал эти строки вместе с данными. Спасибо за замечание.